# Aligning result to the right

Tags: html, css

The code returns the following output on the screen:
1 2 3 4 … 15 16 NEXT

I’ve tried below `align="right"` or `float:right;` but none of them presents the output on the right side of the row. Also, `padding-right:0px` doesn’t help me here.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">
<div style="float:right;"><?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: How about adding `text-align:right` to your styles? It'll only work if you increase the width of your table, so there's somewhere the text can actually move.

Comment: 'text-align:right' doesn't change anything.

Comment: That's because the width of your table is too small, as I mentioned in my previous comment. Try changing its width to something wider, like **100%**

Comment: As the question was reformulated later in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597355/align-result-to-the-right, this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting some width. For example, on your `table`:

`<table style="width:100%">`

Then `<div style="float:right">test</div>` would align to the right-most side of your page (or to the container of the `table`, etc).

Comment: This is what written above, ‘float’ doesn’t do any aligning to the right.
P.S. Sorry that I didn’t mention <table style="width:100%"> but it is at the original code.

Comment: @user1315169 Just tested it myself on that exact raw code and it works for me, so I guess my question is: what else have you got going on? CSS manipulating `table` or its containers? does `table` have any containers?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `text-align:right` instead of `float`.