# Align result to the right

Tags: html, css

I’m asking the same question again, now with more details, hopefully to receive effective solution.

In the code below the output aligned the printing to the right of the row:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%"> 
<tr> 
<td align="right"> 
<div style="float:right;">test</div> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

In the code below the output doesn’t aligned to the right of the row (the output stays on the left side of the row), so `float:right;` doesn’t have any influence on the code:

The function pagination() returns the following:
1 2 3 4 … 15 16 NEXT

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%"> 
<tr> 
<td align="right"> 
<div style="float:right;"><?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?></div> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Any advise regarding aligning the above to the right, would be appreciated.

Comment: show us the complete HTML code of your table (use "View source" in your browser)

Comment: Use `style="text-align: right;"` instead of what you've currently got.

Comment: `float-right` is not for aligning text.

Comment: How it has anything to do with php?

Comment: @David is correct, I believe. `div`s default to `display: block`, so that div is tasking up 100% of the width (and that's why floating is doing nothing).

Comment: we shouldn't downvote all the time. Thanks for the upvote.\

Comment: I’m using Ajax, so “View source” is as follows:

<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectPage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="txtHint"><b>info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: to 'itachi', pagination() is PHP

Comment: i've tried, style="text-align:right;" but it doesn’t have any influence

Comment: put a `style="border:solid 1px red; text-align:right"` on your div and see if the DIV spans the width of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```css
.paginate{ text-align:right; }
```

And assign class paginate to your div?

**Update**

Decalre it as `!important`

```css
.paginate{ text-align:right !important;}
```

See this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mdDMC/)**, it works, so I think you have something else which is taking precedence over the rule.

Comment: Thank you ‘sixeightzero’, I’ve just tried, but still my text line stays on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the div n just put your pagination php inside. because the way i see your div doesnt really do anything except floating to the right.

```
    <td align="right"><?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?></td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did, my text line still stays on the left side.